# How to solve for multiple variable with 2 equations with a list of predefined variables

Tags: matlab

i was given 2 equations with 8 variables total but 6 will be defined. The list of the 6 variables will not stay the same each time.  I want to solve for the changing unknown variables. I was told to try and use fsolve.

the equations are:

```
0=Rao*cos(theta2)+Rab*cos(theta3)+Rbc*cos(theta4)-Rco*cos(theta1);
0=Rao*cos(theta2)+Rab*cos(theta3)+Rbc*cos(theta4)-Rco*cos(theta1)];
```

Where the R's are variables and all the thetas are as well.

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: I got the user to input the known variables and left the unknown blanks then put the 2 equations into a function and called the function into the fsolver but got the error undefined function or variable. im also not completely sure how to use fsolve or start for the script

Comment: Those two equations looks the same to me, (except the `]` on the end of the second one)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Mathworks documentation (https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html), `fsolve` requires at least two arguments: `fun` and `x0`.

`fun` is a function that produces a vector of zeroes when evaluated at the solution.

`x0` is an initial guess for the solution.

In other words, if

```
x = fsolve(fun,x0)
```

then

```
fun(x) = 0
```

In your case, what is `fun` and `x`?

From your question, it's not clear to me exactly what `x` is, but it should be a 2 x 1 vector containing the two unknown variables. (For the sake of this answer, I will assume you want to solve for `Rao` and `Rco` and edit if you update your question.)

`fun` is determined by the equations you have listed. They are already in a format which is 0 on one side of the equation.

Also, from your question, your two equations appear to be identical, which means `fsolve` will find a solution, but it won't be unique. My best guess is that you meant to solve

```
0=Rao*cos(theta2)+Rab*cos(theta3)+Rbc*cos(theta4)-Rco*cos(theta1);
0=Rao*sin(theta2)+Rab*sin(theta3)+Rbc*sin(theta4)-Rco*sin(theta1);
```

So, you can define a function

```
function y = full_function(x)
    y = [x(1)*cos(x(6))+x(2)*cos(x(7))+x(3)*cos(x(8))-x(4)*cos(x(5));
         x(1)*sin(x(6))+x(2)*sin(x(7))+x(3)*sin(x(8))-x(4)*sin(x(5))];
end
```

convert your variable names into components of x and solve with the `fsolve` function

```
x0 = zero(8,1); % Use a different initial guess if you know more about the problem
x_full = fsolve(@full_function,x0);

Rao = x_full(1); Rab = x_full(2);
Rbc = x_full(3); Rco = x_full(4);
theta1 = x_full(5); theta2 = x_full(6);
theta3 = x_full(7); theta4 = x_full(8);
```

But wait. Why is MATLAB solving for all 8 variables? We want to specify 6 of them and solve for 2.

In that case, you can define a new function based off of the the `full_function`, which only takes 2 arguments.

Here, I define an function where the known parameters are filled in, but the unknown parameters are expressed in terms of the new function arguments

```
constrained_function = @(x) full_function([x(1); Rab; Rbc; x(2); theta1; theta2; theta3; theta4]);
```

Now, `fsolve` will only attempt to find values for `Rao` and `Rco`.

So, the full code should look like

```
function q41811094_fsolve_fixed_params()
    % Unknown variables - Enter initial guess
    Rao = 1; Rco = 1;

    % Known variables - Enter known values
    Rab = 1; Rbc = 1;
    theta1 = 0; theta2 = 0;
    theta3 = 0; theta4 = 0;

    % Package guesses for unknown variables
    x0 = [Rao; Rco];

    % Define new function with 6 defined values
    constrained_function = @(x) full_function([x(1); Rab; Rbc; x(2); theta1; theta2; theta3; theta4]);

    % Use fsolve to find 2 remaining values
    x_constrained = fsolve(constrained_function, x0);

    % Unpackage variable values
    Rao = x_constrained(1)
    Rco = x_constrained(2)

end

% Define function for all 8 parameters
function y = full_function(x)
    y = [x(1)*cos(x(6))+x(2)*cos(x(7))+x(3)*cos(x(8))-x(4)*cos(x(5));
         x(1)*sin(x(6))+x(2)*sin(x(7))+x(3)*sin(x(8))-x(4)*sin(x(5))];
end
```